# Disney's Recess Whistles

Tags: props, recess

Is there a name for the whistle-like things they use on Disney's *Recess*? I am fairly certain that they have never given a name for those things on any episode.

If it is a whistle, what kind of whistle is it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are kazoo's.

I found a page hosting the picture you posted [here](http://www.closinglogos.com/page/Logo+Variations+-+Walt+Disney+Pictures) and it clearly states that they are using kazoo's to play the Disney theme.

A Kazoo:

[image]

Comment: same page I found it. didn't bother looking at the text. hahaha thanks

Comment: Should anyone buy one remember to *hum* into it, not *blow* into it. Blowing into the kazoo will tear the wax paper that allows it to make noise.